# ruby 1.9 - what is easiest inverse of `string.codepoints.to_a`?

Tags: ruby, unicode, ruby-1.9

In ruby 1.9.3, I can get the codepoints of a string:

```
> "foo\u00f6".codepoints.to_a
 => [102, 111, 111, 246]
```

Is there a built-in method to go the other direction, ie from integer array to string?

I'm aware of:

```
# not acceptable; only works with UTF-8
[102, 111, 111, 246].pack("U*")

# works, but not very elegant
[102, 111, 111, 246].inject('') {|s, cp| s << cp }

# concise, but I need to unshift that pesky empty string to "prime" the inject call
['', 102, 111, 111, 246].inject(:<<)
```

UPDATE (response to Niklas' answer)

Interesting discussion.
`pack("U*")` always returns a UTF-8 string, while the `inject` version returns a string in the file's source encoding.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: iso-8859-1

p [102, 111, 111, 246].inject('', :<<).encoding
p [102, 111, 111, 246].pack("U*").encoding
# this raises an Encoding::CompatibilityError
[102, 111, 111, 246].pack("U*") =~ /\xf6/
```

For me, the `inject` call returns an ISO-8859-1 string, while `pack` returns a UTF-8. To prevent the error, I could use `pack("U*").encode(__ENCODING__)` but that makes me do extra work.

UPDATE 2

Apparently the String#<< doesn't always append correctly depending on the string's encoding. So it looks like pack is still the best option.

```
[225].inject(''.encode('utf-16be'), :<<)  # fails miserably
[225].pack("U*").encode('utf-16be')  # works
```

Comment: You could also just use UTF-8 as your source encoding.

Comment: Note that `codepoints` does *not* return Unicode codepoints for non-Unicode encodings (e.g. GB18030 is not "Unicode" for this purpose despite encoding all of Unicode).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most obvious adaption of your own attempt would be

```
[102, 111, 111, 246].inject('', :<<)
```

This is however not a good solution, as it only works if the initial empty string literal has an encoding that is capable of holding the entire Unicode character range. The following fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: iso-8859-1
p "\u{1234}".codepoints.to_a.inject('', :<<)
```

So I'd actually recommend

```
codepoints.pack("U*")
```

I don't know what you mean by "only works with UTF-8". It creates a Ruby string with UTF-8 encoding, but UTF-8 can hold the whole Unicode character range, so what's the problem? Observe:

```
irb(main):010:0> s = [0x33333, 0x1ffff].pack("U*")
=> "\u{33333}\u{1FFFF}"
irb(main):011:0> s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):012:0> [0x33333, 0x1ffff].pack("U*") == [0x33333, 0x1ffff].inject('', :<<)
=> true
```

Comment: Nice, should've thought of that. I still wonder if there is a built-in method.

Comment: I added to my question in response to your suggestion to use `pack`. I think inject is still the more general solution.

Comment: @Kelvin: your `inject` approach might be more general in that it can use a string of arbitrary encoding as the seed, but it's certainly less useful when it comes to your actual question of creating a Unicode string from a list of codepoints (as you noted correctly, `'' << codepoint` fails in general if the source encoding can't hold the entire Unicode range). I think we're drifting away here. What's your actual problem?

Comment: Actually I think pack may be better, because `:<<` doesn't seem to pay attention to the receiver's encoding: `[225].inject(''.encode('utf-16be'), :<<)` doesn't return a proper utf-16be string, but `[225].pack("U*").encode('utf-16be')` seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the values in your array and the value of `Encoding.default_internal`, you might try:

```
[102, 111, 111, 246].map(&:chr).inject(:+)
```

You have to be careful of the encoding. Note the following:

```
irb(main):001:0> 0.chr.encoding
=> #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
irb(main):002:0> 127.chr.encoding
=> #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
irb(main):003:0> 128.chr.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
irb(main):004:0> 255.chr.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
irb(main):005:0> 256.chr.encoding
RangeError: 256 out of char range
        from (irb):5:in `chr'
        from (irb):5
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):006:0>
```

By default, 256.chr fails because it likes to return either US-ASCII or ASCII-8BIT, depending on whether the codepoint is in 0..127 or 128..256.

This should cover your point for 8-bit values. If you have values larger than 255 (presumably Unicode codepoints), then you can do the following:

```
irb(main):006:0> Encoding.default_internal = "utf-8"
=> "utf-8"
irb(main):007:0> 256.chr.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):008:0> 256.chr.codepoints
=> [256]
irb(main):009:0>
```

With Encoding.default_internal set to "utf-8", Unicode values > 255 should work fine (but see below):

```
irb(main):009:0> 65535.chr.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):010:0> 65535.chr.codepoints
=> [65535]
irb(main):011:0> 65536.chr.codepoints
=> [65536]
irb(main):012:0> 65535.chr.bytes
=> [239, 191, 191]
irb(main):013:0> 65536.chr.bytes
=> [240, 144, 128, 128]
irb(main):014:0>
```

Now it gets interesting -- ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 don't seem to mix:

```
irb(main):014:0> (0..127).to_a.map(&:chr).inject(:+).encoding
=> #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
irb(main):015:0> (0..128).to_a.map(&:chr).inject(:+).encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
irb(main):016:0> (0..255).to_a.map(&:chr).inject(:+).encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
irb(main):017:0> ((0..127).to_a + (256..1000000).to_a).map(&:chr).inject(:+).encoding
RangeError: invalid codepoint 0xD800 in UTF-8
        from (irb):17:in `chr'
        from (irb):17:in `map'
        from (irb):17
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):018:0> ((0..127).to_a + (256..0xD7FF).to_a).map(&:chr).inject(:+).encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):019:0> (0..256).to_a.map(&:chr).inject(:+).encoding
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
        from (irb):19:in `+'
        from (irb):19:in `each'
        from (irb):19:in `inject'
        from (irb):19
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):020:0>
```

ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 can be concatenated, as long as the ASCII-8BIT codepoints are all in 0..127:

```
irb(main):020:0> 256.chr.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):021:0> (0.chr.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT") + 256.chr).encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):022:0> 255.chr.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
irb(main):023:0> (255.chr + 256.chr).encoding
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
        from (irb):23
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):024:0>
```

This brings us to an ultimate solution to your question:

```
irb(main):024:0> (0..0xD7FF).to_a.map {|c| c.chr("utf-8")}.inject(:+).encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):025:0>
```

So I think the most general answer is, assuming you want UTF-8, is:

```
[102, 111, 111, 246].map {|c| c.chr("utf-8")}.inject(:+)
```

Assuming you know your values are in 0..255, then this is easier:

```
[102, 111, 111, 246].map(&:chr).inject(:+)
```

giving you:

```
irb(main):027:0> [102, 111, 111, 246].map {|c| c.chr("utf-8")}.inject(:+)
=> "fooö"
irb(main):028:0> [102, 111, 111, 246].map(&:chr).inject(:+)
=> "foo\xF6"
irb(main):029:0> [102, 111, 111, 246].map {|c| c.chr("utf-8")}.inject(:+).encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):030:0> [102, 111, 111, 246].map(&:chr).inject(:+).encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
irb(main):031:0>
```

I hope this helps (albeit a bit late, perhaps) -- I found this looking for an answer to the same question, so I researched it myself.

Comment: To add to the above answer, you could do this `[102, 111, 111, 246].map{|cp| cp.chr(__ENCODING__)}.join` or to be more specific `[102, 111, 111, 246].map{|cp| cp.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)}.join`